# Python coding style on function call with multiple parameters

Tags: python

This may sound like a newbie question, but I really need some help with this. I don't even know how to tag it, but I assume is just a Python question. I need to use a function that receives 5 parameters and returns 5 values:

```
a, b, c, d, e = function (input1, input2, input3, input4, input5)
```

The problem is that when I use the full variables/functions names the line is just too long, and the code looks ugly, I want to use a more fancy solution here and I was thinking on using a dict or a list so I can do this:

```
input_dict['param1'] = input1
input_dict['param2'] = input2
input_dict['param3'] = input3
input_dict['param4'] = input4
input_dict['param5'] = input5
ret_dict = function(input_dict)
```

Is there a better or "pythonic" way of improving the code quality of this kind of calls?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't say I entirely understand what it is exactly that you find ugly about the original code, and in what way the `input_dict` version is prettier.

Comment: Note that there is a `dict` literal notation in Python so rather than many assignments, you should construct dictionaries as `{x: y, w: z}`.

Comment: Also, [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) has good recommendations on dealing with line length.

Comment: Thanks Lattyware, this helps me too!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can nest lines like this

```
my_function(test, this, out, like, so,
                   something, indent)
```

You can expand lists into args like so

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
my_function(*a)
```

You can even do this

```
result = my_function(big, long, list, 
                      of, args)
a,b,c,d = result
```

> Also, [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) has good recommendations on dealing with line length. – Lattyware 5 mins ago